# How to multiply two matrices with different rows and columns in MATLAB (Error in matrix dimensions)

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a set of real data with multiple columns and rows. I am having trouble multiplying the `mvdr_algo` in my code that displays this error:
`Results may be inaccurate. rCOND = 1.365229e-27. > In pcm (line 85) Matrix dimensions must agree.`
After generated the Rxx, I'm having this matrice of (5001,5001) and the detaS is (1,1).
So how can I multiply these two matrices? Here is my code:

```
signal_data = abs(signal(5000:10000));%original signal
nbr_mics = 2; %number of microphones
nbr_snap = 200;
thetas = 30*pi/180;
center_frequency = 18000;% carrier frequency
c =3e8; speed of light
lamda = c/center_frequency;
d = 0.5*lamda;
Is = zeros(nbr_mics,1);
for n = 1:nbr_mics
    Is(n) = exp(j*2*pi*(n-1)*d*sin(thetas)/lamda);
end
Rxx = (signal_data.'*(signal_data.')')/nbr_snap; %covariance
detaS = Is;
Wmvdr_algo = inv(Rxx).*detaS.*inv(detaS'.*inv(Rxx).*detaS); %MVDR algorithm
```

Comment: It doesn't look that `detaS` has the dimension (1,1). Because your number of microphones is 2, the variable `Is` has the dimension (1,2) which you assign to `detaS`. Try to extend your loop or try first with one microphone..

Comment: @Till my mistake, detaS is (1,2). It works with one microphone. But, how can I set it to work with two microphones? Thank you

Comment: As I said, you can just extend the loop as an easy solution. Of couse you'll get two different matrices `Wmdr_algo` - one for each microphone.
`...
Wmvdr_algo(:,:,n) = inv(Rxx).*detaS(n).*inv(detaS(n)'.*inv(Rxx).*detaS(n));
end`

Comment: I solved the issue, it works now. Thank you, Mr @Till